# how to get the next two words following '@' in a string with javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am implementing a 'typeahead' friends/followers feature similar to the one seen on Facebook.

When a user types the '@' key in a comment box the next two words need to be checked against a json array of usernames rendering an autocomplete list.

I already have an event currently triggering when the user presses '@', this then sends the full text string into a separate function in which I intend to perform the matching against. I now just need to parse this text and retrieve the text that follows the '@'.

Therefore the actual question is how can I retrieve the text that directly follows a '@' within a string.

The match must be extracted from the **last** occurrence of '@' within the string. (to allow for multiple auto-completes within the same string as the user types.)

Hopefully someone with a better grasp of regular expressions/JS string manipulation could help.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Just to add some examples:

```
@John Smith says hello
```

should return:

```
John smith says hello    OR  simply 'John Smith' - Either is okay for this purpose
```

however this string:

```
I was talking to @John Smith and he told me all about @Sarah Smith
```

should only return:

```
 Sarah Smith
```

Comment: can you post an example input string and your desired output from it?

Comment: of course... I will edit the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is that OK ?

```
txt.substring(txt.lastIndexOf('@')+1).split(' ').slice(0, 2).join(' ')
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dHHq2/1/)

Comment: All good answers so far thank you.  I'm just doing some testing before deciding who I should award the answer to.

Comment: Thanks dystroy, several correct answers here but I have awarded it to you for adding the jsFiddle.  Many thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't use regular expressions, but rather [lastIndexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf)

From my console:

```
var a = "@tony @stark"
> undefined
var b = a.lastIndexOf('@')
> undefined
a.substr(b, a.length)
> "@stark"
```

Or, if you prefer

```
a.substr(b+1, a.length)
> "stark"
```

**Update*

```
function getRest(a) {
  var b = a.lastIndexOf('@'); 
  return a.substr(b+1, a.length);
}
getRest('@John Smith says hello')
> "John Smith says hello"
getRest('I was talking to @John Smith and he told me all about @Sarah Smith')
> "Sarah Smith"
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex would be `/@(\w+ \w+)[^@]*$/` (@ sign, two words, followed by non @ characters until the end of the string). I'm not sure if this is faster than the substring/split approaches.

```
var regex = /@(\w+ \w+)[^@]*$/,
    myString = "@spork and @abe lincoln spam spam spam",
    match = myString.match(regex)[1];
// match == "abe lincoln"
```

Comment: It's probably fast enough and maybe faster than using indexof : regexp are heavily optimized in browsers, especially if they're not dynamic.

Comment: @nrabinowitz - Thanks, this looks good however it returns null if I have only put in the firstname for example having only typed 'Joh' instead of 'John Smith' and I need it to throw back a match even if only part of the first word is typed.

Comment: then use `/@(\w+( \w+)?)[^@]*$/`